# How to create an invert of a dataframe after filtering out rows with certain values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame where there are some rows that have special characters ("+") I want to filter and delete those rows. The "+" is in every column.

```
    Acceleration    Aggression  Agility Balance Ball control    Composure   Crossing    Curve   Dribbling   Finishing   Free kick accuracy  GK diving   GK handling GK kicking  GK positioning  GK reflexes Heading accuracy    ID  Interceptions   Jumping Long passing    Long shots  Marking Penalties   Positioning Reactions   Short passing   Shot power  Sliding tackle  Sprint speed    Stamina Standing tackle Strength    Vision  Volleys
1495    72  80  68  59  68  69  54  59  71  79  44  15  7   6   16  16  69  211899  36  65  48  72  27  66  77  74  68  81  28  77  80  35  81  63  73
1496    54  76  60  53  68  68  44  68  63  46  76  11  14  6   9   9   76  205756  73  79  71  60  74  63  41  74  73  83  77  56  64  76  80  61  43
1497    75+1    66  68+2    64  77  72  75  62  73+2    44  46  15  10  8   13  11  64  193470  73  67+2    74+2    41  78  49  74  72+1    78  56  78+1    74+1    74+2    79  68+1    69  39
```

I tried using

```
df1=df.stack().str.contains(r'[+-/*]')
```

to create a filter but I can't seem to get it to work. What is the better way to process this?

Comment: What special characters do you need to filter out?

Comment: The "+" are the only ones I have seen in the dataset. So for now just the rows with "+".

Answer (score 1):

The space delimiters in the column headers are a bit inconsistent in your sample data.  Simplest way to replace invalid numbers with **NaN** across all columns is as below.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    Acceleration    Aggression  Agility  Balance  Ball control    Composure   Crossing    Curve   Dribbling   Finishing   Free kick accuracy  GK diving   GK handling  GK kicking  GK positioning  GK reflexes  Heading accuracy    ID  Interceptions   Jumping  Long passing    Long shots  Marking Penalties   Positioning Reactions   Short passing   Shot power  Sliding tackle  Sprint speed    Stamina  Standing tackle  Strength    Vision  Volleys
1495    72  80  68  59  68  69  54  59  71  79  44  15  7   6   16  16  69  211899  36  65  48  72  27  66  77  74  68  81  28  77  80  35  81  63  73
1496    54  76  60  53  68  68  44  68  63  46  76  11  14  6   9   9   76  205756  73  79  71  60  74  63  41  74  73  83  77  56  64  76  80  61  43
1497    75+1    66  68+2    64  77  72  75  62  73+2    44  46  15  10  8   13  11  64  193470  73  67+2    74+2    41  78  49  74  72+1    78  56  78+1    74+1    74+2    79  68+1    69  39"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
```